# Centos6.9 install python3.5 display error permission denied after make

Tags: python, linux, bash, gcc

1. CentOS release 6.9 (Final) : Linux version 2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.i686 (mockbuild@c1bl.rdu2.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 13:54:13 UTC 2017
2. Install command :

   `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.4/Python-3.5.4.tgz
   tar -zxvf Python-3.5.4.tgz
   cd Python-3.5.4
   mkdir /usr/local/python3.5
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.5`
3. Error step :

   `make`

   `gcc -pthread -c -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    -Werror=declaration-after-statement   -I. -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE \
         -DGITVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
         -DGITTAG="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
         -DGITBRANCH="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
         -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
   /bin/sh: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied
   make: *** [Modules/getbuildinfo.o] Error 126`
4. the power of /bin/sh and /usr/bin/gcc

   `[root@iZ2814clj1uZ Python-3.5.4]# ll /bin/sh
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May 11  2017 /bin/sh -> bash
   [root@iZ2814clj1uZ Python-3.5.4]# ll /bin/bash
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 872372 Mar 23  2017 /bin/bash
   [root@iZ2814clj1uZ Python-3.5.4]# ll /usr/bin/gcc
   -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 234948 Mar 22  2017 /usr/bin/gcc`
5. I haved tried chmod 777 /bin/sh , /bin/bash , /usr/bin/gcc  and reboot the system, but it doesn't work. Has anyone else had this problem with this ?
   Thanks for any help/suggestions.

update 2017-11-13: selinux audit log

`type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1510502012.108:840): user pid=4273 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=[ip address1] addr=[ip address1] terminal=ssh res=success'
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1510502012.108:841): user pid=4273 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=[ip address1] addr=[ip address1] terminal=ssh res=success'
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1510502012.108:842): user pid=4273 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=destroy kind=session fp=? direction=both spid=4274 suid=74 rport=31432 laddr=[ip address] lport=5676  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=[ip address1] terminal=? res=success'
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1510502012.108:843): user pid=4273 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=success acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=[ip address1] terminal=ssh res=success'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1510502012.109:844): user pid=4273 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=[ip address1] addr=[ip address1] terminal=ssh res=success'
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1510502012.109:845): pid=4273 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=0 old ses=4294967295 new ses=106
type=USER_START msg=audit(1510502012.111:846): user pid=4273 uid=0 auid=0 ses=106 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=[ip address1] addr=[ip address1] terminal=ssh res=success'
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1510502012.189:847): user pid=4273 uid=0 auid=0 ses=106 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=[ip address1] addr=[ip address1] terminal=ssh res=success`

Comment: Is there anything in the SELinux audit log?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Can you help me to check my audit log?

Answer (score 0):

Today,I found the answer. I haved install a security software, which prohibited create and excute binary file in the system directory. So I uninstalled it and my system back to normal.

Comment: But I still dont know how that security software make it prohibited?

Answer (score -1):

Download miniconda from https://conda.io/miniconda.html. Miniconda is the light version of Anaconda from continuum. It comes with the latest python -v and virtual env, and package installer 'conda'.

```
cd /tmp
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
sudo bash ./*.sh
```

When it prompts for install directory use

```
/home/user/.miniconda3
```

You don't have to do this but placing it in a hidden directory reduces the clutter.

Conda handles virtual envs and package installations.

1. To create an environment, conda create -n newEnv python="python version"
2. To start an environment, source activate newEnv.
3. To install packages, conda install "something"
4. Some packages, may not be available on conda so you use pip , within the environment.
5. I use Ubuntu, so I install pip via, sudo apt-get install python-pip.
6. Upgrade pip by, python install --upgrade pip

See conda cheatsheet, https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try later.

Answer (score -1):

It's still the same issue http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2014/08/installation-of-python-2-6-error-fixed/

My advice is to stick with "yum install python3" and save your time. I think they're on 3.4 right now, of course if you don't need something specific from 3.5.